# Why is my "for" loop not iterating through completely?

Tags: python, for-loop, cryptography

I'm very new to python and have been working on cryptography. I was working on a Caesar Cipher but towards the end of the code, it stops working and only encrypts 1 of the chars in the string.

Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

```
during = []
preBool = True
while preBool == True :
    pre = str(input("Enter your message: "))
    if pre.isalpha() == False:
        print("\nSorry, your input was not recognized.")
        print("-------------------------------------------------------")
        continue
    else:
        preBool = False
for char in pre:
    during.append(char)
print(during)

while True:
    try:
        rot = int(input("Enter the rotation value: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, your input was not recognized.")
        continue
    else:
        break
#Here is where I'm having issues. 'Cipher' only prints the first letter.
def encrypt(pre,rot):
   result = ""
   # transverse the plain text
   for i in range(len(pre)):
      char = pre[i]
      # Encrypt uppercase characters in plain text

      if (char.isupper()):
         result += chr((ord(char) + rot-65) % 26 + 65)
      # Encrypt lowercase characters in plain text
      else:
         result += chr((ord(char) + rot - 97) % 26 + 97)
      return result

print ("Cipher: " + encrypt(pre,rot))
```

Answer (score 1):

`return result` is inside the `for` loop. When the code hits it, it exits the function unconditionally, breaking out of the loop in the process.

De-indent it by one level and the `for` loop should run as intended, and only `return` after it has run its natural course.